# How to deserialize json and retrieve specific property values in c#

Tags: c#, json

I'm quite new to JSON with C# (Using VS2017). Tried accessing each element of this object via code (e.g. Getting the strings `"Obj1"`, `"Obj2"`, `"Obj3"` and then the values of each of their members (Id and name).

I do not know in advance how many "ObjX" there will be or their names. I'm trying to load this list into some class and then convert it into a CSV (or SQL inserts).

Tried with JSON.net and JsonFx but I think my skills are just not strong enough to understand how to do this other than brute-force string manipulation functions. Can anyone help?

```
{  
"OBJ1":{  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Name1",
},
"OBJ2":{  
      "id":2,
      "name":"Name2",
},
"OBJ3":{  
      "id":3,
      "name":"Name3",
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6620165/11683)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3142495/11683)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class, MyClass with two properties, int Id and string Name.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Then, depending on how you want to do it you can either deserilize it to a Dictionary or create a MyClassRoot object with three MyClass properties.

I recommend the Dictionary approach.
If you use the Dictionary approach your code will still work if more properties gets added to the JSON. If you use the `MyClassRoot` solution you will need to add the corresponding property to the MyClassRoot if the json updates.

Then with JSON.Net you can deserialize the object like this.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, MyClass>>(json);
```

The "OBJ1", "OBJ2" and so on will then be keys in the dictionary and you can access the values like this:

```
var obj1 = result["OBJ1"];
var obj1Name = obj1.Name;
var obj1Id = obj1.Id;
```

To get all the `MyClass` objects to a list, simply do the following:

```
var list = result.ToList();
```

MyClassRoot approach(not recommended at all, just a POC):

```
public class MyClassRoot
{
    public MyClass Obj1 {get;set;}
    public MyClass Obj2{get;set;}
    public MyClass Obj3{get;set;}
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClassRoot>(json);
var obj1Name = result.Obj1.Name;
var obj1Id = result.Obj1.Id;
```

Comment: Ok - I need to provide some more details, 1st approach is more valid.

There could be infinite ObjN in the response and I'd like to load them into a list.

Comment: Moreover - I don't know the names of "Obj1", "Obj2" in advance, they could be new values which I haven't seen yet.

What I'm trying to build is something that converts this json into a CSV, with code (I know there are online converters but that's not my goal)

Comment: You guys are amazing - THANKS!